# Consume 32 bit REST Service in 64 bit Client

Tags: 32bit-64bit

We have few legacy 32 bit dlls which are required to be consumed by a 64 bit process.As per my knowledge,this cannot be achieved without implementing a process bridge using COM+.The approach is really difficult and comes with lots of strings attached . Also,there is no concrete example available on the approach and nowhere a success story adapting this approach has been heard.

As an alternative,we are planning to expose the dlls as REST services to consume from 64 bit process. In that case, we would wrap the dlls in ASP.NET MVC Web API methods and would build Web API project in 32 bit (x86) platform.

Would this approach work? Does REST/SOAP protocol has any bit dependencies on the underlying process?

Also, if anyone can suggest any alternative approach that would help us.

Comment: REST/SOAP are text-based protocols. The processor involved is irrelevant.

Comment: I understand that.But if I want to expose my 32 bit dlls using REST/SOAP the hosting process has to be a 32 bit process. In that case if I am consuming the service methods from 64 bit client, would it be problem due to bit mismatch between the provider and consumer processes?

Comment: It really depends on what data you're sending to those DLLs. You usually can't expose a raw DLL over SOAP. You need to write a wrapper layer and that's where you'll have to evaluate how to transport data. So long as you're not doing binary payloads the platform should be irrelevant.